# Importing a windows project into android using cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, android, cocos2d, cocos2d-x

What I am trying to do today is to import a full project to Android, but no tutorials are available for that that I have seen. My approach was to create a new android project, copy all the classes and resources in the folders and calling ./build_native.sh but I get an error because most of the files are not being included in the project. I tried opening the Android.mk and I can see why "LOCAL_SRC_FILES := AppDelegate.cpp \ HelloWorldScene.cpp" are the only files linked.

Should I manually modify the make file or can it be automated by some way I don't know?

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

I manually added all files and headers to the make file and I get errors linking Box2D or cocosdenshion libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the library naming, as the standard Android project has the library names as "cocos2d" (my project had cocos2dx) and "cocosdenshion" (case sensitive into "CocosDenshion")

Answer (score 1):

just add every file with cpp extention in your project into "LOCAL_SRC_FILES list", and of course if you don't have a file named "HelloWorldScene.cpp", remove it from that list.

**UPDATE**

I'm not sure this time but I'm guessing from what I can see inside test project:
there are two file with name "android.mk"

1. jni\android.mk
2. jni\tests\android.mk (or equivalent address based on your project name)

in the first file add

```
subdirs := $(addprefix $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../,$(addsuffix /Android.mk, \
    Box2D \
    cocos2dx \
    CocosDenshion/android \
    ))
```

note that `$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../` should point at cocos2dx root folder change it if it is not correct

and in the second file this line should do the trick

```
    LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := cocosdenshion_shared box2d_shared
```

Comment: I just added an update:

UPDATE:

I manually added all files and headers to the make file and I get errors linking Box2D or cocosdenshion libraries.

Comment: @EfEs updated my answer.

Comment: I did test it, it correctly imports the libraries but I can't say it is the answer because I still get a lot of project-related problems, sorry :(

Comment: I tried using another build_native from previous version and everything looks like working, but I get realtime problems when calling System.loadLibrary("cocos2d");

If you want to help send me a message or we can talk in chat. Thanks.

Comment: The problem was that someone else had updated the libraries in the SVN under a different name.

Question closed.

Comment: @EfEs so post your answer and accept your answer. that's how things work around here!